# Regex to convert SQL INSERT statement to dictionary of key,value

Tags: c#, sql, regex

I need a Regular expression to convert SQL INSERT statements into a dictionary of key,values. The value can be a complex formula.
The strategy I've used is the C# groups and captures.

For example

> A->RIC_MIGRATION
>
> B->RIC_MIGRATION
>
> C-> AND ( ( IN ( CurrencyStr , "AUD","NZD","EUR" ) ) ,  AND ( 1, AND ( 1, AND ( ( FeedToPXE2 = "1")  , ( RIC_CRED_ValueSource = "1")  , ( FeedToPXE1 = "0")  , ( IN ( InsType , "A","C","T" ) ) , )) , ) , )

I've tried the below

```
var insertRegex = @"INSERT INTO (?[A-Z_]*)\(((?[""A-Za-z_]+),?)*\) VALUES\(((?'[^']+'),?)*\)";
var inputString=@"INSERT INTO TABLEA(A,""B"",C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M) VALUES('RIC_MIGRATION','RIC_MIGRATION','AND ( ( IN ( CurrencyStr , ""AUD"",""NZD"",""EUR"" ) ) ,  AND ( 1, AND ( 1, AND ( ( FeedToPXE2 = ""1"")  , ( RIC_CRED_ValueSource = ""1"")  , ( FeedToPXE1 = ""0"")  , ( IN ( InsType , ""A"",""C"",""T"" ) ) , )) , ) , )','','','EUR.CM_INSTRUMENT.REFDATA.INSTRUMENTGROUP_PXECRED_RIC_MIGRATION','1','1','0','','','0','No')";
var regMatch = Regex.Match(inputString, insertRegex);
```

but it doesn't match.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for looking

Comment: The regex you're using looks complex and scary to me.  Is there any chance you could just dump the SQL data and build a dictionary from, e.g., a flat file?

Comment: I smell syntax errors in your regex.

Comment: Found the error.Correct Regex is var insertRegex = @"INSERT INTO (?<table>[A-Z_]*)\(((?<keys>[""A-Za-z_]+),?)*\) VALUES\(((?<values>'[^']*'),?)*\)";

Comment: (1) What problem are you actually trying to solve? This looks like a potential XY problem to me. (2) Can you give a complete set of requirements? You're clearly only trying to match a specific subset of regex, so can you clarify exactly what would constitute a "complete" solution, in the context of your problem? (3) If you've found the answer, please post it as an answer! Not as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The correct Regex is

```
var insertRegex = @"INSERT INTO (?[A-Z_]*)\(((?[""A-Za-z_]+),?)*\) VALUES\(((?'[^']*'),?)*\)";
```

Handles the empty string values ''